# cin Operator Chaining to Streamline System Output

Tags: c++, loops, io, cin

Good afternoon,

I have some code that asks the user to input a number to get some polynomial values for. The first number is the number of polynomials desired to input (int N), the following numbers are pointers to values in a linked list and input in sets of coefficient (int &coe) and power (int &pow).

When I run the program it will prompt the user for the requisite values each time. However, if you enter all the values at once, it will output the prompt N times. Is there a way that I can set a control that will identify how many inputs I have, and then correctly output the number of prompts needed before computing the values?

e.g. If I input 3, it wants 3 sets of numbers, and I could do it one set at a time, or all at once/ If I input 3 4 9 3 0 5 7, then it would skip the "Enter ..." message and continue. Likewise, if I input 5 for the polynomial request, and input 5 8 5 3 7 6 4, it would only print the message once and still have two sets to go before continuing with the program.

Code:

```
int N = 0;
printf("Enter N polynomials: ");
cin >>N;
Node *node = NULL;
int pow, coe;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    printf("Enter coeff. & pow. of poly.: term %d separated by \" \": ", i);
    cin >> coe >> pow;
    createNode(coe, pow, &node);
}
```

Comment: Which `cin` are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I was using printf as cin, the code has been adjusted to reflect the question

Comment: _" I was using printf as cin"_ Now you find me totally confused? Isn't `printf()` for output?

Comment: The closest pure C++ approach you're probably going to get is to read an entire line of input using `getline()` and then read values from that into your individual variables, then prompt for what you need next.  To actually determine whether multiple lines have been provided in advance (by redirecting input from a file, or pasting multiple lines from the clipboard, etc) is beyond the ken of standard C++ I/O and needs to use some OS-specific code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::getline()` to read the users input into a `std::string`, and then use `std::istringstream` to read integers from that string until there is none left, then go back to `std::cin` and prompt for more integers as needed.

```cpp
int N = 0;
cout << “Enter N polynomials: ";
cin >> N;
string input;
getline(cin, input);
istringstream iss(input);
Node *node = NULL;
int pow, coe;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    if (!(iss >> coe >> pow))
    {
        cout << “Enter coeff. & pow. of poly.: term “ << i << ” separated by \" \": ";
        cin >> coe >> pow;
    }
    createNode(coe, pow, &node);
}
```